# Frequency Redshift at infinity

Tags: general-relativity

I have the following problem:

> Suppose a test particle is radially freely infalling towards the Schwarzchild radius (r=2M). Suppose the particle is sending out a monochromatic electromagnetic signal out to $r=\infty$. The observer at infinity measures a redshifted wavelength $\lambda_{\infty}$ such that
> $$\lambda_{\text{particle}} \sim \lambda_\infty e^{-t/k}$$
> where $k$ is a constant when the test particle is very close to crossing the horizon. Express $k$ in terms of the mass of the black hole.

**Attempt at a solution:**
The frequency redshift for the Schwarzchild metric is
$$\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2} = \frac{(1-2M/r_2)^{1/2}}{(1-2M/r_1)^{1/2}} = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}$$

Where $M$ is not the proper mass. I'll be taking $r_1 \to \infty,$ so
$$\lambda_\infty (1-2M/r_2)^{1/2} = \lambda_{\text{particle}}$$
I need this in terms of $t$ so I look at a null geodesic:
$$0=-(1-2M/r)dt^2 + (1-2M/r)^{-1}dr^2$$
$$(dt/dr)^2 = (1-2M/r)^{-2}$$
$$\Delta t = \pm \int_{r_1}^{r_2} (1-2M/r)^{-1}dr = \pm (2M\ln(r-2M)+r)\Big|_{r_1}^{r_2}$$
$$\Delta t =(r_1 -r_2) + 2M\ln \frac{r_1 -2M}{r_2 - 2M}$$

I'm not really sure how to take it from here. I don't understand how to change the expression involving $r_1,$ and $r_2$ into one involving $t.$ Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your expression for the redshift is only true for static observers, whereas in this case you have a freefalling object emitting the signal.

Comment: @JohnRennie why do you think that is a duplicate? It doesn't even deal with the Doppler shift. For the record, I voted to close this as "homework".

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213441/do-free-falling-observers-see-gravitational-blueshift

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved by deriving a correct expression for $\lambda_{\infty}(r)$. Then by differentiating with respect to $t$ we get
$$\frac{d\lambda_\infty}{dt}=\frac{d\lambda_\infty}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}.$$

If the right hand side is $\propto \lambda_{\infty}$ as $r \rightarrow r_s$, then I think you have your answer.

Comment: I am confused, what is $\lambda(r)$ here? Is that the wavelength emitted by the falling observer at point $r$?

Comment: @Jbag1212 should be $\lambda_{\infty}$ (as a function of $r$). Works for me. Simple answer.

Comment: What is $r_s?$.

Comment: @Jbag1212 $r_s = 2M$.